# python valueError write()

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I try pip install things, it doesn't work
and return

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py",
>   line 1566, in _writecheck
>       raise ValueError("write() requires mode 'w', 'x', or 'a'") ValueError: write() requires mode 'w', 'x', or 'a'

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you installing? Please share the exact command.

Comment: Please provide the command and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission issue.   I'd try making sure your python folders all have the same permissions.